# How do I add a TapGestureRecognizer to a label inside a cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I subclassed a UITableViewCell.  I tried to add the gesture recognizer, but nothing happens when I tap it.

```
class MessagesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    var profileTap:UITapGestureRecognizer?


    func render(){
        if profileTap == nil {
            print("Here") //prints.
            profileTap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
            profileTap?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MessagesTableViewCell.profileTapped(_:)))
            nameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(profileTap!)
        }
    }


    func profileTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer!){
        print("tapped")
    }
}
```

I don't need my cell to be selectable. I just need the label to be.

Comment: where do you call render from? Are you adding the recognizer as the cell getting created in your cell for row method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the label's `userInteractionEnabled` property is true, UILabel's are not user interactive by default.

```
label.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Alternatively, use a UIButton.

Comment: Make sure userInteractionEnabled is true for the entire view hierarchy above it too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a gesture recognizer there? Much better way is to use a clear UIButton in binding with simple block:

```
var closeHandler:(()->())?


@IBAction func profileTapped(sender: UIButton!){
    if let handler = closeHandler { handler() }
}
```

And in your cellForRow: method:

```
    cell.closeHandler = {
            //do your stuff
        }
```

Comment: Why add a hidden button when you can use a gesture recognizer for exactly it's intended use? How is it "better"?

Comment: Because "A UIButton object is a view that executes your custom code in response to user interactions." So it's a special class provided Apple to you for this situation. You can change its frame. use its layer o draw something, it has its own UILabel, so you don't need to have another one to display a text. It has different states, and you can show to user what is the current one right now and so on and so on.

Comment: If you had told him to replace his label with a button I would have been all for that.  You told him to use a clear UIButton which does none of the things you just said except respond to user interactions which a gesture recognizer already does.